# How to use compiler builtin functions without Standard C library

Tags: c++, c, gcc, optimization, built-in

I know that some functions like `sin` `cos` `min` `max` `memcpy` may be treated not as normal functions but may be replaced by [built-in functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins) (which may be more optimal than merely inline function calls, when the replacement is (an) actual processor instruction(s), such as directly calling the `FSIN` instruction for standard `sin` function when compiled for an x86 with a floating point unit).

The question I would like to use power of built-in functions (in C/C++ mostly in mingw/gcc maybe other compiler) but I do not want to link to libc, the Standard C Library).

- Is it possible to use builtins with not linking to libc?
- Are they any command line flags needed to optimize those symbols as a built-ins?

  *(Related to previous, but rephrased)*
- Will they be automatically recognized by name, or are compiler flag(s) necessary to enable usage of built-ins?

Comment: @FUZxxl As the question asker may not be a native English speaker, the may use abbreviations because they are uncertain of the correct spelling. Also some seemingly basic typing mistakes may be due to using a non-English (e.g. US/UK) keyboard and the key-mapping for punctuation can be problematic. Also if you have enough experience, feel free to contribution to StackOverflow by improving the question with spelling and grammar corrections yourself.

Comment: Related: [How GCC handles built-in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930588/how-gcc-handles-built-in-function?rq=1) and various [nostdlib Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nostdlib).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say you wanted to replace the function `cos`, all you have to do is replace every occurance of `cos` in your code with `__builtin_cos`.  The same goes for any other function that you can replace with the compiler's version.  Just prepend `__builtin_` to the name.

For more information consult the [gcc manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html).

Comment: but to be sure if i understood, i may this way prefix (take reference) those functions that given compiler can generate as biult ins? (like sin min memcopy, no other?) Also no need for giving any c-lib header or something?

Comment: Which you would normally do with a `#define cos __builtin_cos` to explicitly force the compiler to use the builtin version instead of the C library versions.

Comment: when i tested some function double f(double y) { return __builtin_sin(y);} and compile it to .o it gave only "jmp 00 00 00 00" as a whole assembly, does maybe someone know why?

Comment: Note that, as the manual explains, `__builtin_XXX()` may in some cases still generate a call to the library function, so this is not a guaranteed solution.  This is probably what happened in @user2214913's test (with the `jmp 00 00 00 00` to be replaced by the linker with the library function's address).

Answer (score 5):

@randomusername has already explained the usage of the [`__builtin_`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins) prefix for many common Standard C Library functions. I recommend using `#define` to make the change, while keeping your code clean.

```
#include <math.h>

#define  cos   __builtin_cos
#define  sin   __builtin_sin
#define  printf __builtin_printf

...
   printf("Distance is %f\n", cos(M_PI/4.0) * 7);
...
```

---

### No Standard C Library

Now to not **use** the Standard C Library, which means not linking to it, or including the typical startup and exit code stubs, well, with GCC that is possible with the `-nostdlib` which is equivalent to `-nostartfiles` and `-nodefaultlibs`.

The issue is that you then have to replace **all** the library functions you would normally use, including [system calls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) (or their [wrappers](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/SyscallWrappers) / macros from glibc) for any kernel based functions.

I don't know of a [portable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729497/doing-a-syscall-without-libc-using-arm-inline-assembly) or robust method that works across processors or even [necessarily](http://articles.manugarg.com/systemcallinlinux2_6.html) different [families](http://justanothergeek.chdir.org/2010/02/how-system-calls-work-on-recent-linux/) (sysenter vs. syscall (*instruction*) vs. `int 0x80` for various 32 and 64-bit x86 processors). There is issues with *ELF Auxiliary Vectors* (`Elf32_auxv_t`) and [vDSO](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html)  (*virtual ELF dynamic shared object*) that may be possible to address and create a portable solution, I don't know.

### Entry Point

I believe all GCC environments use the same default entry point, which is the label/function `_start`. This is normally included in the "Startup files" and then calls the traditional C/C++ entry point of `main`. So you would need to replace it with a minimal stub of your own (which can be in C).

### Program termination

I don't know how to replace `_exit(rc)` or similar function required to correct terminate the program, in a portable fashion. For example in a Linux environment it needs to make a system call to the kernel function [`SYS_exit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994106/system-calls-difference-between-sys-exit-sys-exit-and-exit) (aka `__NR_exit` or `sys_exit`)

```
void _start(void) {
    int rc;
    /* Get command line arguments if necessary */
    rc = main(0, NULL);
    your_exit_replacement(rc);
}
```

### Alternatives

Normally *user processes* i.e. application programs, as opposed to Operating System kernels or drivers, accept the overhead of linking the Startup Files and the necessary overhead to enable [dynamic linking](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/dl-libraries.html) to the Startard C Library, as memory is considered cheap and readily available that for any real (actually does something) application the memory saving is not worthwhile. In embedded domain, where it is not as acceptable to just assume plenty of memory is available, the alternative is the use a minimal libc replacement. For Linux there are several available (e.g. musl, uClibc, dietlibc), I don't know if there is one available for mingw or Windows-compatible open source replacements (ReactOS, and Wine).

### Further

For further information, from a Linux platform point of view, there is a nice introduction ["Hello from a libc-free world!" Part 1](https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/hello_from_a_libc_free) and [Part 2](https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/hello_from_a_libc_free1) by Jessica McKellar blogging at Oracle. There are also a number of related questions, and some (partial in some cases) answers here at [stackoverflow about using -nostdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nostdlib) in various circumstances.

Where to go from here depends on your goals: education, embedded, [tiny program](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) (Linux ELF executable) or Windows [PE executable](http://www.phreedom.org/research/tinype/) competitions.

### Microsoft Windows

There are various articles for a Microsoft Windows environment dealing with .COM and .EXE executables, and Windows PE but using Microsoft's Visual Studio environment or assembly typically.  The "classics" are Matt Pietrek's Under the Hood column ["Reduce EXE and DLL Size with LIBCTINY.LIB"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb985746.aspx) (January 2001 issue of MSDN Magazine) and ["Remove Fatty Deposits from Your Applications Using Our 32-Bit Liposuction Tools"](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/archive/S572.aspx) from October 1996 Microsoft Systems Journal. Another article, but I haven't read myself, that appears to have include explanations is ["Reducing Executable Size"](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/reducing-executable-size).

Comment: tnx, method for what, and solution for what? -nostdlib seem to work this throwed out 1000 asembly lines of some startup code was previously put in my exe, winapi calls when use -luser32 seem to work too.. though i dont know how to set an entry point because first function in my source is called regardless of the name.. could someone hint on that

Comment: alright tnx for long explanation, sorry i cannot set an answer as prevvious user was faster and i cannot get back it i thin it would be unfair, anyway tnx